# React Native : react-native run-android gives an error

Tags: react-native, classpath

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.

> Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11.
>        Required by:
>            project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:gradle-core:3.1.4 > com.android.tools.build:builder:3.1.4 > com.android.tools:sdklib:26.1.4 > com.android.tools:repository:26.1.4
>   Could not resolve org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.2.11.
>   Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.pom
>   Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-runtime-parent:2.2.11.
>   Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-runtime-parent:2.2.11.
>   Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-runtime-parent/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-parent-2.2.11.pom
>   Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-parent:2.2.11.
>   Could not resolve com.sun.xml.bind.mvn:jaxb-parent:2.2.11.
>   Could not parse POM https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/xml/bind/mvn/jaxb-parent/2.2.11/jaxb-parent-2.2.11.pom
>   Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.

Comment: Which react-native package have you linked recently ?

Comment: I ejected this project from expo. But all react-native projects in my computer gives this error

Answer (score 0):

It is related to your android gradle version. try to update your gradle version by 3.1.4 as its written. "Required by: project : > com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4"